# Modify the <head> tag of a page from a module using Joomla core functions

Tags: joomla-3.x, metadata, header-tags

I'm going to explain: I'm new to Joomla! and I have 3 modules in which I have to rewrite the URLs for SEO purposes.

In order to rewrite URLs has been provided [this solution](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/106564/45880) on SE WebMasters. It implies me to add a `<link>` tag in the `<head>` of the page so I would like to know if there is a Joomla-core method with which I can add such tag in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, below is the code. 
`$doc = JFactory::getDocument(); 
$doc->addHeadLink(htmlspecialchars(JURI::current()), 'canonical');`

I was looking for the Joomla documentation and only found one from Joomla 1.7.  Not sure if the documentation just hasn't been updated or there have been some changes. 
https://docs.joomla.org/API17:Subpackage_Document

Comment: addHeadLink() isn't a core php function - so it can't be called like this - this should be JDocumentHTML::addHeadLink(); or $doc = JFactory::getDocument(); $doc->addHeadLink();

Comment: Thanks @FFrewin, I made the edit.  I just did a sloppy copy/paste from file on my computer.  Do you know if the documentation is just out of date or are they moving away from this?

Comment: haven't check the link you posted - although this is the J17 API - and currently I don't have the time to review and compare the old API with the new one for any differences.